# How to fill in large paint chips on a wood door?

Tags: paint

We have a very old house. The interior doors have been painted probably a dozen times.

One of my kids got interested in picking at a small crack in the paint on one of the doors and couldn't stop. :). The gap is around 2" wide and 3" tall.

I want to repaint the whole door, but first fill in the gap because it currently has so many layers of paint.

Is spackle the wrong tool?

I do NOT want to strip / sand the whole door.

[image]

Comment: How good do you want it to look? You could just sand down the rough edges and live with the dip. Spackle will show through, as the existing paint has a grain/brush texture you cannot re-create with spackle. Well maybe you could by making a silicon/wax/sillyputty cast of the texture and pressing it into the wet spackle. It would be the best to strip that whole side of the door, and it doesn't look like that would be difficult if a child can do it. A pressure washing would probably remove 90%...

Comment: Please consider most houses built prior to 1978 are likely to contain lead paint. Before sanding,scrapping  or stripping remove the door from the house. If your children are  young enough to eat things they shouldn't  purchase a Lead Test Kit at a big box store.